# How to DOWNLOAD "lazy" loading Images ? <img loading="lazy"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation-testing

I had used JavaScript-executer & was able to find the `ImageElement`, But further when I try to extract the URL(for downloading the image.svg ), I am getting an error "NoSuchElementException ",  below is my Code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation/','_blank');");                     
wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));         
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));  
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;   

By Image=By.xpath("//img[@title='Jenkins']");            
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");           
      //  Below commented snippet is giving Error 
/*WebElement ImageElemnt =driver.findElement(Image); 
   String src = ImageElemnt.getAttribute("src");    
    System.out.println(src);*/



wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(Image))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Explanation :

The first line of your code is

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation/','_blank');");
```

which basically means is you are trying to open `https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation/` in a new **tab**. Selenium does not know until you tell this to Selenium that you have to switch to different tab now for further execution.

So, your line of code should be something like this

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation/','_blank');");  
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
```

**Update 1 :**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation/','_blank');");
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//img[@title='Jenkins']")))
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
String src = ele.getAttribute('src')
System.out.println(src);
```

Comment: if that is the case , then How does the last line  work ?

Comment: is that open a new window  ? or do you have `driver.get()` not before this ? why would one use js to open a new windows. also mention which last line you are referring to ?

Comment: This is one of the Segment of complete Code. I already have one tab open for another page previously(using driver.get() ). Here, i have opened new tab for this link & trying to download the image.

Comment: Did you try to switch like I have suggested ? if not, do that first and share the entire error stack trace if there's any

Comment: Also how did you conclude that this line is working  ? is it this line `js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");    ` ?

Comment: I can see , the Webpage is Scrolled to the End

Comment: ideally it should not, cause you are opening a new tab and not switching to it. so it should not.

Comment: Here the Entire Code, Please have a look ; https://github.com/sam-rac/Lambdatest_Test_1/blob/master/src/test/java/Page/LoginPage.java

Comment: @samrac : See the updated 1 code above, it works for me